# Найден текстовый домен wp-bootstrap-navwalker в теме WordPress

Tags: wordpress

В разработке темы вордпресс  при проверке плагином theme check высвечивается такая ошибка

Warning: More than one text-domain is being used in this theme. This means the theme will not be compatible with WordPress.org language packs.
The domains found are irfas, wp-bootstrap-navwalker

Внимание: в этой теме используется несколько текстовых доменов. Это означает, что тема не будет совместима с языковыми пакетами WordPress.org.

Может, кто-то знает, где и как найти и удалить этот текстовый домен wp-bootstrap-navwalker? Просмотрела wp-bootstrap-navwalker.php но ничего там не нашла.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По всем .php файлам темы надо провести поиск на `'wp-bootstrap-navwalker'`. Такая текстовая строка должна содержаться в вызове функция gettext типа `__()`, `esc_html__()` и т.п. Пример:

```
$next = __( 'Next', 'wp-bootstrap-navwalker' );
```

Вам надо заменить строку `wp-bootstrap-navwalker` на `irfas`. Потом обновить файл .po из исходных кодов, перевести новые строки, подхваченные из бывшего текстового домена `wp-bootstrap-navwalker`, скомпилировать в .mo. Для работы с файлами .po и .mo есть редактор poedit.

Comment: с  файлами .mo и .po я еще пока не работала не знаю что там и как, но поискала строки такого типа  $next = __( 'Next', 'wp-bootstrap-navwalker' );    и заменила в файлах  nav-menus.php и class-wp-bootstrap-walker.php все значения  'wp-bootstrap-navwalker' на 'irfas'. Проблема ушла и сейчас стало                                                                              
       ИНФОРМАЦИЯ: Only one text-domain is being used in this theme. Make sure it matches the theme's slug correctly so that the theme will be compatible with WordPress.org language packs.
The domain found is irfas

Comment: $fallback_output .= '<li><a href="' . esc_url( admin_url( 'irfas' ) ) . '" title="' . esc_attr__( 'Add a menu', 'irfas' ) . '">' . esc_html__( 'Add a menu', 'irfas' ) . '</a></li>';
    $fallback_output .= '</ul>';

Comment: папка темы должна называться irfas, тогда не будет такого сообщения

Comment: она так и называется. А да я забыла что я назвала ее irfas.loc